# Is any google calendar api for iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, calendar, google-calendar-api, gdata-api, gcal

Is there any google calendar api for iphone sdk, currently I develop an iphone calendar native application. In this application i want to sync with google calendar from both side. So i want to know is there any google calendar api for this work.

I found [iphone-gcal-example](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-gcal/) but it shows errors because it has missing GData Source files. Is there any other example which sync or add events to google calendar.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi did u have this api??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are official APIs from Google in Objective-C which work on Mac OS X and iPhone/iPad:

http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/

Comment: this example will only fetch google events how can i fetch google calendar tasks.

Comment: @Apekshit Search for Google Task API. It is another Google project (not calendar). http://code.google.com/apis/tasks/

Comment: How can i get event color from iphone-gcal-example ?

Comment: @Apekshit Maybe search for your question and (if not found) ask a this question here in stackoverflow.com . Sorry I'm not a expert of this API.

Comment: code.google.com/apis/tasks cannot provide any task api it shows only methods names... can you provide me url where these api is uploaded ?

Comment: can this be used for iphone?

Comment: @Durgaprasad yes. It is for both: OS X and iOS (iPhone, iPad, iPod)