# iOS: Google Calendar Example

Tags: ios, google-calendar-api

Searching around the net for almost 1 day I still did not see any simple good example of an app that implements the Google Calendar API. Or even simple explanation on how to implement the API is still not available. Can someone help me please? I'm a newbie to iOS. I need to learn how to create an event using the Google Calendar API through my app in iOS. I need a sample simple code...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is any google calendar api for iphone sdk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840231/is-any-google-calendar-api-for-iphone-sdk)

Comment: @BradLarson  have you done the google calendar API? And you get any other sample code. Am waiting for your reply.

Comment: There really aren't many simple, thorough examples of this.

Comment: you can do from here : https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/ios

Answer (score 3):

Here are some very useful links when trying to figure out the google calendar api. http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/wiki/GDataObjCIntroduction and mainly http://code.google.com/p/iphone-gcal/. I just downloaded the source code from the second link and worked from there. It was great!

Comment: But there is "GData Sources" files are missing.

Answer (score 1):

The Google Calendar API, like most Google API's, provides a straightforward REST interface. Instead of focussing first on how to create calendar events, learn [how to interact with a RESTful web service](http://blogs.captechconsulting.com/blog/jack-cox/tutorial-simple-iphone-rest-client). Once you know how to do that, you only have to learn what calls to make to accomplish your goal, and that's [already well documented](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/v3/using.html).